# Perfect way to split a x265 video losslessly using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

What would be the right way to cut a clip from a high-quality x265 video? Lets say I want to extract a part from 5min22sec to 5min59sec without losing any quality using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way is

```
ffmpeg -ss 05:22 -t 0:37 -i input.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero output.mp4
```

Because x265 uses temporal compression, FFmpeg may include frames before and after the cut-point, which are needed to decode the specified range. The `avoid_negative_ts` does some housekeeping to make sure that the output plays nice with most players.

For exact but lossless cutting, use

```
ffmpeg -ss 05:22 -t 0:37 -i input.mp4 -c copy -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 output.mp4
```

But this tends to produce bloated video streams. In practice, a low CRF should provide an acceptable result.

```
ffmpeg -ss 05:22 -t 0:37 -i input.mp4 -c copy -c:v libx265 -crf 22 output.mp4
```

Comment: Should we really consider 22 as a low CRF? Isn't it possible  to know the input CRF and keep the same value?

Comment: The CRF isn't the same as a quantizer, so it's about using a value that looks visually lossless compared to the source. It's possible to know the source CRF in Mediainfo, provided the SEI hasn't been stripped off.